# How to allow all special characters in textbox only one time using JS?

Tags: javascript

My textbox should accept only special characters only once.
for example:
It should not allow '%' symbol more than once.
All the special characters should be allowed only once in my textbox in JS.
I tried so many answers in stackoverflow but failed to get the exact code.
'Like *so*'

```
`/^(?=[a-zA-Z,]*['.-][a-zA-Z,]*$)[a-zA-Z,'.-]+$/`
```

Here instead of apostrophe, dash and period , I tried '%' but its allowing as many *Percentages* (%) as can.

Comment: Any reason it must be regex? Or can you use Nicks answer?

Answer (score 1):

Write an event handler that catches keypresses on your textarea.  Have it check `event.which` against the characters in the textarea.  If it isn't allowed, return false or call event.preventDefault() and the character will not be inputted.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict more than one same character in textbox using Regex?

Comment: I'm not sure where a regex even figures in here.  Are you trying to prevent the person from typing the character in the first place, or just displaying an error to them if they did?

Comment: Is your question about how to prevent a user from typing a character, or how to write a regular expression for this?  I still think it would be easier without a regular expression though, since all you have to do is check if the character the user just typed already exists in the input.

Comment: sir !! i have mentioned everything about my requirement briefly. please go through my answer and reply for the same... 10~Q sir...